# AWS S3 filenaming when using MediaConvert

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, media

I am currently uploading files to an Amazon S3 using MediaConvert via Lambda functions.  However part of my processing is to create thumbnail images from uploaded videos.  To do this I am using the AmazonMediaConvetClient and creating a job request.

However the files that are generated have a suffix applied to them of 0000000 which from what I can gather is in reference to the frame captured.

However I do not want this suffix on the filename. Is there anyway to ensure that the filename created from a video thumbnail is what I specify with no suffix?

```
var jpgOutput = new Output
                    {
                        NameModifier = $"-Medium",
                        ContainerSettings = new ContainerSettings { Container = ContainerType.RAW },
                        Extension = "jpg",
                        VideoDescription = new VideoDescription
                        {
                            CodecSettings = new VideoCodecSettings()
                            {
                                Codec = VideoCodec.FRAME_CAPTURE,
                                FrameCaptureSettings = new FrameCaptureSettings()
                                {
                                    MaxCaptures = 1, Quality = 100
                                }
                            },
                            Height = thumbnail.Height,
                            Width = thumbnail.Width
                        }
                    };
```

In the code snippet above the file is created as 1-Medium.000000.jpg but I want 1-Medium.jpg

Comment: Did you manage to solve this afterwards?

Comment: Sorry Ivan, been away from this for a while.  I don't think I did through the utilities available.  I think I ended up stripping it via code after the fact.  Not ideal but from memory that worked.

Comment: You mean, after you saved it in the S3 bucket (with suffix), you renamed it? We decided that we won't spend too much time on it, so we adjusted our backend to it (suffix) and everything is alright. Therefore, we won't be doing any changes unless needed.

Comment: Glad you found a solution.  Yes I think that's correct.  We saved it, then renamed it after to what was needed.  Wasn't ideal, but sounds like you have found something that works too.